# Automatically run rule when file changes in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake, inotifywait

When working on compiled documents (LaTeX, RMarkdown, etc), I usually set up a rule for `make` using `inotifywait` to watch the input files and automatically rebuild the output file whenever the input files change.

For example:

```
dependencies = main.tex

main.pdf: $(dependencies)
    latexmk -lualatex --shell-escape $<

watch:
    while true; do inotifywait --event modify $(dependencies); $(MAKE); done
```

I'm now trying to migrate from `make` to `snakemake`. How can I set up something similar with `snakemake`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Snakemake you get the power of Python. For example, you can use `inotify` python module to wait for updates and run the `snakemake.snakemake` function each time you detect updates. But it would be much easier to reuse the bash script that you have already: `while true; do inotifywait --event modify $(dependencies); snakemake; done`.